# Cuando veo mi pagina en en el navegador google chrome mi imagen de fondo no se ve?

Tags: html, css

Al cargar mi pagina en el navegador de google chrome no se ve pero en los demás navegadores si y al quitarle el estilo de background-attachment:fixed; si se ve pero no hace el efecto que quiero de pasar por atrás de un rgb y que la imagen se vea en el fondo, la imagen se queda estatica. Repito esto solo me pasa en google chrome.
La imagen va en el footer de fondo el rgb va en la section la cual esta encima del footer.

La imagen si se ve en ese ejemplo porque estoy viendo la pagina en internet explore pero en google chrome no se ve la imagen.

```
<div class="contact col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

  <footer class="" style="width:100%; background-image:url(img/fg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; margin-top:50px; background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed;">

    <section id="vacio" style=" height:600px;  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); width:100%;">

      <!--map-->
      <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="padding-top:13%;">

        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3598.4883955475957!2d-103.7" width="100%" height="290px" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

      </div>
      <!--map-->

    </section>

  </footer>

</div>
```

Asi se ve en chrome

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esa imagen de fondo a la que te refieres es del footer, por lo que muestras ahí o estas hablando del fondo del sitio en total?, creo que deberías aclarar esas cosas y mostrar alguna imagen que respalde eso, ya que con el código que muestras solo estas haciendo un cambio en el pie de la página.Saludos.

Comment: background-image:url(/img/fg.jpg);

Comment: o esta mala la ruta de la imagen o el contenido del `footer` cubre todo el espacio del mismo por lo que no se ve la imagen

Comment: puedes subir tu ejemplo a codepen.io ? o alguno parecido para ayudar

Comment: listo ahi esta la imagen esa esta cargada con IE11 por lo que la ruta no esta mal

Comment: incluye la captura de chrome, y de la herramienta de desarrollador (DevTools) F12

Comment: podrias abrir la consola de chrom y ejecutar document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].getAttribute("style"); y mostrarnos el resultado .... una vez que haya cargado la pagina

Comment: Esto fue lo que aparece al ejecutar: document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].getAttribute("style");____
                                                                                            
 "width:100%; background-image:url(img/fg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%; margin-top:50px; background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed;"

Comment: que tamaño tiene la imagen original?

Comment: La Imagen tiene un tamaño de 1680 x 945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate si en tu chrome se ve este snippet.

- <s>Bootstrap 4.1</s>
- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- imagen de fondo cargada desde web

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<body style="padding:20px 0; background:#e43;margin:0">
  <div class="contact col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <footer class="" style="width:100%; background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1680/945/?random); background-repeat:no-repeat; margin-top:50px; background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed;">

      <section id="vacio" style=" height:600px;  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); width:100%;">
        <!--map-->
        <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="padding-top:13%;">
          <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m13!1m8!1m3!1d748.4268550806544!2d2.1770822!3d41.380441!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m2!1m1!2sPla%C3%A7a+de+George+Orwell!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sar!4v1532468854303" 
            width="100%" height="290px" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <!--map-->
      </section>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: si, si se ve yo estoy usando bootstrap 3.3.7 y no no se ve y si trato de cambiarme a 4.1 me cambia toda la estructura.

Comment: ok me fijo de usar la 3.3.7 y probamos de nuevo, sino puede ser que el archivo de imagen esté medio roto o tenga un formato que explorer deja pasar y chrome no lo carga

Comment: actualizado el bootstrap

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar ya agregue tus enlaces quite los míos hasta la url de la imagen y ni asi y ya lo probe en varias computadoras.

Comment: si cambias `img/fg.jpg` por `https://picsum.photos/1680/945/?random` sigue sin verse?

Comment: Si ya lo hize y sigue sin verse nada

Comment: si no carga `https://picsum.photos/1680/945/?random` en local pero sí lo carga desde aquí tendrás que revisar todos los css que se cargan, alguno debe estar complicando el position para el chrome

Answer (score 0):

Corri tu ejemplo con una imagen local.

En tal caso lo que faltaba es la altura del footer.
lo dejo en 600px pero fíjate tu cual te conviene.

```
<footer class="" style="width:100%;height:600px; background-image:url(img/fg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; margin-top:50px; background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed;">
```

Comment: si ves la imagen que anexe te darás cuenta que no hay problema con eso puesto que lo cargo en IE11 y se ve bien pero en chrome no se ve nada.

Comment: Si lo se no carga fue cortado a propósito.